# OpenCV Java: Compare Bounding Rect's y value, clear unwanted

Tags: java, android, opencv

In the picture below, the application detected multiple "black" and drawn a bounding rectangle around them. Now **I want to compare the `rect3.tl().y` values of each rectangle and only keep the lowest one, deleting the other bounding rectangles.** But I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

[image: picure]

**Code:**

```
Rect rectBlack = new Rect();
    Bitmap roiBitmap = null;
    Scalar green = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);
    Mat sourceMat = new Mat(sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(sourceBitmap, sourceMat);

    Mat roiTmp = sourceMat.clone();
    bitmapWidth = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
    Log.e("bitmapWidth", "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    final Mat hsvMat = new Mat();
    sourceMat.copyTo(hsvMat);

    // convert mat to HSV format for Core.inRange()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(hsvMat, hsvMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    Scalar lowerb = new Scalar(85, 50, 40);         // lower color border for BLUE
    Scalar upperb = new Scalar(135, 255, 255);      // upper color border for BLUE

    Scalar lowerblack = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);         // lower color border for BLACK
    Scalar upperblack = new Scalar(180, 255, 40);      // upper color border for BLACK

    Scalar testRunL = new Scalar(60, 50, 40); // lower Green   83 100 51
    Scalar testRunU = new Scalar(90, 255, 255); // upper Green

    Core.inRange(hsvMat, lowerblack, upperblack, roiTmp);   // select only blue pixels
    // find contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    List<RotatedRect> boundingRects = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(roiTmp, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // find appropriate bounding rectangles
    for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
        MatOfPoint2f areaPoints = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
        RotatedRect boundingRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(areaPoints);

        double rectangleArea = boundingRect.size.area();

        // test min ROI area in pixels
        if (rectangleArea > 1300 ) {
            Point rotated_rect_points[] = new Point[4];
            boundingRect.points(rotated_rect_points);
            Rect rect3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(new MatOfPoint(rotated_rect_points));


            // test horizontal ROI orientation
            if (rect3.height > rect3.width) {
                Log.e("w,h", String.valueOf(rect3.width)+ " h " + String.valueOf(rect3.height));
                double w = rect3.width;
                double h = rect3.height;
                double ratio= h/w;

                    Log.e("h:w ratio", String.valueOf(ratio));
                    Log.e("Black Area", String.valueOf(rect3.area()));
                    Imgproc.rectangle(sourceMat, rect3.tl(), rect3.br(), green, 3);
                    rectBlack = rect3;
                    Log.e("blackArea", String.valueOf(rect3.area()));
                    xBlack = rect3.br().x;
                    xBlackCenter = (rect3.br().x + rect3.tl().x) / 2;
                    yBlack = rect3.br().y;//bottom
                    battHeight = (rect3.br().y - rect3.tl().y); //batt height in pixel


            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list of rects:

```
List<Rect> rects = new ArrayList<>();
```

then in your `for (MatOfPoint contour : contours)` loop add each founded rectangle to that list:

```
// find appropriate bounding rectangles
for (MatOfPoint contour : contours) {
    ...
    // test horizontal ROI orientation
    if (rect3.height > rect3.width) {
       ...
       rects.add(rect3)
    }
}
```

then use method to find bottom-most rectangle, like that:

```
public static Rect getBottomMostRect(List<Rect> rects) {
    Rect bottomMostRect = null;

    if (rects != null && rects.size() >= 1) {
        Rect rect;
        double minY;
        int ixMinY = 0;

        rect = rects.get(ixMinY);
        minY = rect.tl().y;

        for (int ix = 1; ix < rects.size(); ix++) {
            rect = rects.get(ix);
            if (rect.tl().y < minY) {
                minY = rect.tl().y;
                ixMinY = ix;
            }
        }

        bottomMostRect = rects.get(ixMinY);
    }

    return bottomMostRect;
}
```

and call it this way:

```
Rect bottomMostRect = getBottomMostRect(rects)
```

Or add `getBottomMostRect()` implementation directly into your `for (MatOfPoint contour : contours)` loop.

Comment: Quick note: the larger the `minY` value the  "lower" the black object is in the picture, so the if  else statement should look something like this: `if (rect.tl().y > minY)` Other than that I have no issues with the code, thank you so much for all your help, this and other of my questions included.

Comment: Oh! Yes, you are right! Of course You should find maxY, not min.